# React Native Firebase write user data after account creation

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working with Firebase and React Native I have come to a slight problem.

Reading the [documentation for the: **createUserWithEmailAndPassword**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword):

> On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application.

I was trying to work with the promise as follows:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
.then(function(authData){
    this.writeUserData(authData.uid);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.warn(error)
});
```

And my `writeUserData()` method:

```
writeUserData(the_uid) {
    console.warn("Writting data ")
    var today = new Date();
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.uid + '/').set({
        name: this.state.name,
        birthday: this.state.date,
        email: this.state.email,
        registered: today
    });
}
```

**In the function however the `console.warn` is never fired hence the event isn't fired since the user is automatically logged in.**

**Problem:** The `.then` isn't executed since user is logged in straight away.

**Goal:** Be able to add the user information (name, birthday, etc) after user creation before sign in.

Comment: So what is the issue? You seem to be logged in hence `writeUserData` wont be called?

Comment: @RyanTurnbull yes exactly the .then isn't executed

Comment: why do you want it to be executed? wouldnt you have already written the data to firebase when initially creating the account?

Comment: @RyanTurnbull as mentionned in the documentation: createUserWithEmailAndPassword only takes one email and password as parameters

Comment: Sorry, im having trouble figuring out your situation. why do you want the .then to be executed?

Comment: to also add the data on the sign up page (name, birthday, etc)

Comment: @RyanTurnbull `firebase.auth()` ≠ `firebase.database()`

Comment: yeah my bad, i thought he was wanting to call writeUserData after his app had automatically logged him in, not making a new account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay understood you, the problem seems to be how you define a function in your `.then` statement. You should be using an **Arrow function**, like so -

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then((authData) => {
        this.writeUserData(authData.uid);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.warn(error)
    });
```

Comment: Now I feel so stupid just as you wrote the answer i figured it out haha

Comment: Not as stupid as me :P I thought you had some auto-login feature and couldn't figure out why you would want to call this code if you already had an account

Comment: Monday blues‽ It's Tuesday! This was a rollercoaster haha, glad we got there eventually!

Answer (score 0):

what i have understand is that you are trying to push (name ,birthday , etc ) to firebase , well with my little experience using firebase , you have to call {firebase.database().ref().child('your path')} to create a path first , then use the push()  , exemple :

{ var ref = firebaseRef.database().ref().child('Clients');
        var ref = ref.push(this.state.username); }

well i m newbie , but this worked for me , hope it help you